# No applicable aggregate method 'FirstOrDefault' exists

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

We are building search query using dynamic link . There one property has one to many relationship. There for we use FirstOrDefaylt. But when it going to execute it gives message of "No applicable aggregate method 'FirstOrDefault' exists".

This is the query we have written:

```
var saleYear = dictionary["saleYear"] != null ? dictionary["saleYear"].ToString() : "";
var saleNo = dictionary["saleNo"] != null ? dictionary["saleNo"].ToString() : "";
var lotNumber = dictionary["lotNumber"] != null ? dictionary["lotNumber"].ToString() : "";
var markID = dictionary["markID"].ToString() != "0" ? dictionary["markID"].ToString() : "";                

quer += saleYear != "" ? "Sale.SaleYear=\"" + saleYear + "\"" : "";
quer += saleNo != "" ? quer.Length > 0 ? " and Sale.SaleNumber=\"" + saleNo + "\"" : " Sale.SaleNumber=\"" + saleNo + "\"" : "";
quer += lotNumber != "" ? quer.Length > 0 ? " and InvoiceSales.FirstOrDefault().LotNo=\"" + lotNumber + "\"" : "InvoiceSales.FirstOrDefault().LotNo=\"" + lotNumber + "\"" : "";
quer += markID != "" ? quer.Length > 0 ? " and EstateID=" + markID : "EstateID=" + markID : "";
```

execution point:

```
var _invoiceList = _tbBOSSWebEntities.Invoices.Where(quer)
            .OrderBy(orderQuery);
```

Is this query wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: So what is the value of `quer` at this point? How you've constructed that isn't terribly relevant...

Comment: Am I getting it correctly that you are trying to use FirstOrDefault within the where?

Comment: @JonSkeet value of 'quer'  is ' "Sale.SaleYear=\"2015\" and Sale.SaleNumber=\"041\" and LotNo=\"1401\"" '.

Comment: @Thomas yes. I try to use FirstOrDefault within the where.

Comment: No you don't - not according to the value of `quer` that you've just added as a comment. Again, we don't need to see any of the code that creates `quer` (i.e. in your first snippet) - we just need to see the value of `quer` that you're using at the point of execution.

Comment: @ChathurangaLiyanage what jon means is that it is easier to se the exact problem when you post what quer is around the time the error is thrown.

Comment: what is `InvoiceSales`?